# cash division error in C with floating points

Tags: c, floating-point, int, division, cs50

Im currently working on the cs50 "cash" problem: estimating the amount of coins needed to pay some change.

ex: $0.41 owed = 1 quarters, 1 dime, 1 nickel, 1 penny.

however, when estimating the amount of coins needed i end up being off with the pennies i believe is due to error on my part as it always seems to be off by one or 2 coins (pennies).

I have included multiple printf statement to try and track what i could be doing but i can't seem to figure out why the division isn't working.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    // change
    float change = get_float("how much change is owed?: ");
    int coins = 0;

    //reprompt
    while (change < 0)
    {
        change = get_float("how much change is owed?: ");
    }

    //quarter
    float quarter = 0.25;
    float quarters = change / quarter;
    quarters = (int) quarters;
    change = change - (quarters * quarter);

    printf("%f quarters\n", quarters);

    //dimes
    float dime = 0.10;
    float dimes = change / dime;
    dimes = (int) dimes;
    change = change - (dimes * dime);

    printf("%f dimes\n", dimes);

    //nickels
    float nickel = 0.05;
    float nickels = change / nickel;
    nickels = (int) nickels;
    change = change - (nickels * nickel);

    printf("%f nickels\n", nickels);
    printf("%f in change left change\n", change);

    //pennies
    float penny = 0.010000;
    float pennies = change / penny;
    pennies = (int) pennies;
    change = change - (pennies * penny);

    printf("%f pennies\n", pennies);

    //coins
    coins = quarters + dimes + nickels + pennies;
    printf("%i\n", coins);

    //printf("%f\n", change);
}
```

Comment: Did you try checking [cs50.se]?

Comment: yes, however their built in help function is not able to help me.

Comment: You are probably having this problem: `(int)0.99999 == 0`. Floating point operations are very tricky.  You could solve it by using only integer operations (considering pennies as the base unit).

Comment: I recommend not using `float` at all for this task. Just use `int` to keep track of the amount of pennies. So a dime wouldn't be `0.1`, it would be `10`, etc.

Comment: Your `printf` statements fail to show the correct values. `%f` rounds values to six digits after the decimal point. To show full values `%.99g` suffices for these cases, if your C implementation formats correctly, and `%a` will show the exact values using hexadecimal floating-point format.

Comment: @CacahueteFrito: The fact that `(int)0.99999` evaluates to zero is not the cause of this error. Had the calculation for each coin been performed correctly, the quotient would equal or exceed the number of that coin needed. E.g., for `dimes`, the result could be 1 or some number near 1.1 or .9; it could never be .99999. Therefore, the error is in other calculations, not in the conversion of `float` values to integer values.

Comment: Who gave you this assignment, or where did you get it? Was there advice given about the properties of floating-point arithmetic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your C implementation, these lines:

```
float dime = 0.10;
float nickel = 0.05;
float penny = 0.010000;
```

sets `dime` to 0.100000001490116119384765625, `nickel` to 0.0500000007450580596923828125, and `penny` to 0.00999999977648258209228515625. This results in the calculation for each coin being slightly off. Furthermore, the calculations of `change` after processing each coin have rounding errors.

To fix this, after getting `change` with `get_float`, convert it to a number of cents with:

```
int cents = roundf(change * 100);
```

Then perform all calculations with integer arithmetic. (Include `<math.h>` to get the declaration of `roundf`.)

Answer (score 1):

Start with this line:

```
#include <math.h>


#define PENNIES_IN_GBP (100)


int main(void)
{
        int change_pn = roundf(PENNIES_IN_GBP * get_float("how much change is owed?: "));

        /* ... */

        return 0;
}
```

The rest should be easy ;)

Comment: `roundf` will round to an integer number of dollars, losing the number of cents.

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion, why not perform all the calculations in integer arithmetic? Convert the float "change" into an integer "cents"

```
(int) cents = roundf(100.0 * change); // see comments below answer
```

Then keep everything as integers thereafter, for example

```
//quarter
const int quarter = 25;
int quarter_count = cents / quarter;
cents = cents % quarter; // use modulus operator
```

May I also respectfully suggest that using variable names which are very similar, for example quarter and quarters, is likely to cause errors.

As you will never want to change the number of cents in a quarter (especially accidentally) you can declare it as a const int.

You might also want to check that the user has entered a decimal (float) amount that they believe to be dollars rather than an integer number of cents. But this is beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: `(int) (100.0 * change);` is faulty because `change` may be less than the desired value. For example, if the user inputs “.41”, `change` will be 40.99999964237213134765625, and `100.0 * change` will be 40.99999964237213134765625, resulting in `cents` being 40 when it should be 41.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil - Fair enough. It should be `(int) (100.0 * (change +0.5));` which will round to 41 for any value of `change` within 41 +/- 0.5

Comment: For input of “.41”, `(int) (100.0 * (change +0.5))` produces 90. You would need `100 * change + .5`. But there is no need to cobble together your own rounding function. The `<math.h>` library has functions for that, such as `roundf` and `lroundf`.

Comment: OK Eric, point taken. It's been a long time since I wrote C in anger and I'd forgotten those functions. That was the way we did it in the days before `round` was introduced (1999 I believe).
In any case, the main point of my answer was that it is better to do the calculations in integer arithmetic and avoid all the gotchas of float-to-int conversions and rounding errors. Even I fell into one!