# Greedy algorithm in C not returning any values?

Tags: c, while-loop, cs50, greedy

I'm attempting to write a greedy algorithm with input that should return the smallest number of coins to be used in the change, but it's not returning any values. I am not sure why. It just asks for input, then displays nothing.

I made a previous thread where a bug was determined that resulted in an infinite loop, which was squashed, but now there seems to be another underlying bug in my logic.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <math.h>

// declare variable change_owed, num_coins, and input globally
float change_owed = 0;
float input;
int num_coins;

int main(void)
{
    // makes sure the input is non-negative
    do
    {
        input = get_float("Amount paid\n");
    }
    while(input <=0);

    // begin checking 
    while(input > 0)
    {
        if(input - .25 >= 0) // quarters
        {
            num_coins++; // number of coins used, to be printed later, is incremented
            input = input - .25; // coin is subtracted from total
        }
        if (input - .10 >= 0) // dimes
        {
            num_coins++;
            input = input - .10;
        }   
        if (input - .05 >= 0) // nickels
        {
            num_coins++;
            input = input - .05;
        } 
        if (input - .01 >= 0) // pennies
        {
            num_coins++;
            input = input - .01;
        } 
    }
    printf("%i", num_coins);
}
```

Comment: First, this isn't an [mcve]. I have no idea what "cs50.h" or `get_float` is.  You need to post a minimal compilable example and you need specify the exact input you are giving and how your program is failing to give the output you expect on this input. Secondly, please do NOT use floating point numbers for currency.  You will get burned at some point in time doing this, trust me.

Comment: Does the program terminate?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp No, it does not.

Comment: What happens when input = 0.50? The first pass of the loop subtracts a quarter, then a dime, then a nickle, then a penny.  Don't you want to subtract two quarters?

Comment: `while(input > 0)` Probably floating point issues. For example `input = 0.000001` Obligatory link: [Is floating point math broken?](//stackoverflow.com/q/588004)

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Thank you!

Comment: Note also, that this won't produce the "smallest number of coins". To do that, try changing all the `if` statements to `while` statements. Added bonus, you can remove the outer `while(input > 0)`.

Comment: ,,,or make the second and subsequent "if"s into "else if"s, so that the loop stays on quarters until all the quarters are exhausted, then dimes, etc. And of course NEVER use float for money. Convert the input to integer cents and do the math on that.

Comment: Who gave you this assignment, or where did you get it? Was there advice given about the properties of floating-point arithmetic?

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker: It is not correct advice never to use floating-point for money. Floating-point is suitable for things such as Black-Scholes option evaluation and a number of other purposes.

Comment: I do think it's good advice in general. Any programmer writing code for the exceptions is probably experienced enough to know when to break the rules.

Comment: Actually be very glad this happened to you on a 20 line assignment. You'll probably never forget. Imagine finding yourself in a situation where you have to rewrite and test 20,000 lines of code after changing double to decimal.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker: I see. I misinterpreted “NEVER” as meaning “at no time in the past or future; on no occasion; not ever,” with EMPHASIS.

Comment: @EricPostpischil It's from Harvard's CS50, and it recomends using floats and rounding them.

Comment: @JohnAllison: If it recommends rounding them, why didn’t you round them? What happens if you do? Is the class teaching about `float`, or is its use incidental to the assignment? (I am asking because people ask about this [frequently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56130276/cash-division-error-in-c-with-floating-points), and knowing the context would help to shape answers.)

Comment: @EricPostpischil I didn't catch it at first, stupidly. I fixed it up, but now while inputs such as .41 produce valid results, the input .01 (part of their test) is producing 2 coins.

P.S. I kept trying to show my code but the comment format wasn't allowing me to format it right.

Answer (score 5):

In the commonly used format for `double`, `.10` is not .10 but is 0.100000001490116119384765625. Also, you are using `float` variables (`float input`) with `double` constants (`.10`, `.05`, `.01`). At some point, your program has a remaining amount of money such as .00999…5 that is less than a penny, so it has no coin to subtract from it, so the code loops forever without subtracting anything. To fix that, as soon as you get the `input`, multiply it by 100, round it to the nearest integer (as with `int cents = roundf(input * 100);`), and use integer arithmetic for the rest of the calculations.

Once you have done that, your program will start producing results, and you will need to rethink the `while` and `if` structures you have, as mentioned in some of the comments.